# Can i insert multiple row in one shot?

Tags: java, mysql, performance, hibernate, jpa

I have scenario where I need to insert n rows in a table where only one column value will varies rest will be constant.

I am under impression that there is no way to insert n records in one shot. Please correct me if I am in wrong.

thanks in advance.

I was trying with below query

```
INSERT INTO table1 (project_id,assumption_id,VALUE,created_at,updated_at)
VALUES (SELECT id FROM projects WHERE custom=0),7622,NULL,'2013-09-10 17:18:49','2013-09-10 17:18:49');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference documentation says that:

> Only the INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... form is supported; not the INSERT
>   INTO ... VALUES ... form.
>
> The properties_list is analogous to the column specification in the
>   SQL INSERT statement. For entities involved in mapped inheritance,
>   only properties directly defined on that given class-level can be used
>   in the properties_list. Superclass properties are not allowed and
>   subclass properties do not make sense. In other words, INSERT
>   statements are inherently non-polymorphic.

So if you already have a select criteria to use for your insert you can then run:

```
int createdEntities = s.createQuery( "insert into DelinquentAccount (id, name) select c.id, c.name from Customer c where ..." )
    .executeUpdate();
```

Another option is to use [batch JDBC inserts](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/sect-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Entity_Beans-Batch_Inserts.html) and for this you need to set the following Hibernate properties:

```
<property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="50"/>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="30"/>
<property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="50"/>
```

For update, you can use [DML-style bulk UPDATE](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html#batch-direct):

```
int updatedEntities = s.createQuery( "update YourEntity set yourProperty = :newValue where yourProperty = :oldValue" )
    .setString( "newValue", newValue )
    .setString( "oldValue", oldValue )
    .executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it I guess.

Why not just do a loop?

```
While ($x <= $limit){
 // insert query goes here
}
```

Comment: yes I am trying to do it by looping but in this each insert will create separate DB call right?

Comment: No. What do you mean by DB call

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You just need to create a new object every time, and not reuse the old one and just change some of its fields.

```
MyObject obj;
for (...) {
    obj = new MyObject(...);
    session.save(obj);
}
```